# Test Upload/Download files using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I need your advice on approached to Testing the perf on Jmeter for this Scenario

The application --Its a Windows desktop App where I can add a file and send it to a receiver--who can then download it on their end.

More details--The Desktop App talks to a Upload Rest API on sender side to upload the file to cloud and on the receiver side I have the download API which downloads the file from the cloud.
So basically the Desktop APP/API runs on two different machines(sender and receiver).

Problem - I need to test the Upload and download times taken for various file sizes for ths sender and receiver. The complexity for me here is as follows:

1) I guess I can't test a desktop App using JMeter, So I decided testing the rest API which sits behind the UI layer --So use the API for triggering uploads and download--Is it correct?

2) As the Upload and download API run on different machines or virtual machines --how can I use JMeter to test it?

Feelin lost!!!
Please advice

Comment: Googling for "how to test rest api with jmeter" could be a start point.  SO isn't really for questions like "how can I use jmeter?".

Answer (score 1):

If your application supports proxy connection you should be able to use JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) to capture both sending and receiving requests.

If not - you can use a sniffer tool i.e. [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) to inspect requests and build them manually in JMeter.

Finally you can take a look at [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) to find out proper test elements configuration to simulate file uploads and downloads.